# "Anchor" button inside an adjacent pre

Tags: html, css, button, emacs, org-mode

I'm working on styling for a coding blog I'm creating and I'm trying to get the copy buttons to work just right...

I want both copy buttons to align with the top of the **pre**s, whether a label is provided or not. Would prefer if it were somehow *anchored* to the **pre**.

Better would be to move the copy buttons into the **pre**s (via inline?). i.e., overlapping the upper-right corner of the **pre**. I do not care if it overlaps with text from the **pre**.

Limitation: I cannot move any HTML elements into or out of the "org-src-container" **div**s. I cannot move the label before  (without writing additional `lisp` code, which I'd like to avoid). I can make any arbitrary changes before of after the "org-src-container" blocks. I'm looking for a CSS (or JS) solution given this HTML constraint.

If it's easier for styling, I can move the copy button before the "org-src-container", instead of after. Full disclosure, I'm using Org mode to publish .org markup files into HTML.

Below demonstrates my issue.

```css
.source-block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

pre {
  padding: 8pt;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 1.2em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

pre.src {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top: 1.2em;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  color: #fafafa;
}

.copyBtn {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.org-src-container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <p>
Here is source block meant to represent the contents of a file. Thus, I'm including a label with the filename. The copy button is [approximately] aligned with the label row. This is too high, looks like copying the filename.
  </p>

  <div class="source-block">
<div class="org-src-container">
  <label class="org-src-name"><span class="listing-number">Listing 1: </span>example_file.sh</label>
  <pre class="src src-sh">#!/bin/bash
echo "line 1"
echo "line 2"
echo "line 3"
echo "line 4"
echo "line 5"
echo "line 6"
echo "line 7"
echo "line 8"
echo "line 9"
</pre>
</div>

<button class="copyBtn" name="btn_88a6f2445cdb4d8a8afe4717103f341f">copy</button>

  </div>

  <p>
Here is a source block meant to communicate commands to be run interactively. Thus, there is no filename and I am omitting the label.  The copy button is [approximately] aligned with the first row of the source block. This is nearly where I want it, except that it's not overlapping the pre.
  </p>

  <div class="source-block">
<div class="org-src-container">
  <pre class="src src-sh">echo "command 1"
echo "command 2"
echo "command 3"
echo "command 4"
echo "command 5"
echo "command 6"
echo "command 7"
echo "command 8"
echo "command 9"
</pre>
</div>
<button class="copyBtn" name="btn_6b6c6f15f31f4a1cb9f8af9bcf6c5e7d">copy</button>


  </div>
```

Comment: don't mix the use of double and single quotes; also, please wrap all the attribute values with quotes. Last, your button names are strange, how come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a CSS only solution that will consider both cases (with or without label)

```css
.source-block {
  display: grid;
  margin-top:0.5em;
}
.source-block .org-src-container,
.source-block button {
  grid-row:1;
  grid-column:1;
}
.source-block button {
  margin: 1.5em 1.5em auto auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
.source-block .org-src-container label {
  display:block;
  transform:translateY(-0.5em);
}
.source-block .org-src-container pre:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top:0;
}

pre {
  padding: 8pt;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 1.2em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

pre.src {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top: 1.2em;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  color: #fafafa;
}

.copyBtn {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.org-src-container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>
Here is source block meant to represent the contents of a file. Thus, I'm including a label with the filename. The copy button is [approximately] aligned with the label row. This is too high, looks like copying the filename.
  </p>

  <div class="source-block">
<div class="org-src-container">
  <label class="org-src-name"><span class="listing-number">Listing 1: </span>example_file.sh</label>
  <pre class="src src-sh">#!/bin/bash
echo "line 1"
echo "line 2"
echo "line 3"
echo "line 4"
echo "line 5"
echo "line 6"
echo "line 7"
echo "line 8"
echo "line 9"
</pre>
</div>

<button class="copyBtn" name="btn_88a6f2445cdb4d8a8afe4717103f341f">copy</button>

  </div>

  <p>
Here is a source block meant to communicate commands to be run interactively. Thus, there is no filename and I am omitting the label.  The copy button is [approximately] aligned with the first row of the source block. This is nearly where I want it, except that it's not overlapping the pre.
  </p>

  <div class="source-block">
<div class="org-src-container">
  <pre class="src src-sh">echo "command 1"
echo "command 2"
echo "command 3"
echo "command 4"
echo "command 5"
echo "command 6"
echo "command 7"
echo "command 8"
echo "command 9"
</pre>
</div>
<button class="copyBtn" name="btn_6b6c6f15f31f4a1cb9f8af9bcf6c5e7d">copy</button>


  </div>
```

Comment: Damn, you're a CSS god! Works great! This would've taken me weeks to develop piecing together online guides. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your CSS and HTML structure as follow. The main changes are to set the outer container (`.org-src-container`) to `display: relative` and the copy button to `display: absolute`. Also, I changed the HTML structure in order to have only the `<pre>` block and the button inside the container.

```css
.source-block {
    
}

pre {
    padding: 8px; /* do not use "pt" in CSS */
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 1.2em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

pre.src {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 1.2em;
    background: #0a0a0a;
    color: #fafafa;
}

.copyBtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.2em;
    right: 1.7em;
}

.org-src-container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<p>Here is source block meant to represent the contents of a file. Thus, I'm including a label with the filename. The copy button is [approximately] aligned with the label row. This is too high, looks like copying the filename.</p>

<div class="source-block">
    <label class="org-src-name"><span class="listing-number">Listing 1: </span>example_file.sh</label>
    <div class="org-src-container">
        <pre class="src src-sh">#!/bin/bash
        echo "line 1"
        echo "line 2"
        echo "line 3"
        echo "line 4"
        echo "line 5"
        echo "line 6"
        echo "line 7"
        echo "line 8"
        echo "line 9"
        </pre>
        <button class="copyBtn" name="btn_88a6f2445cdb4d8a8afe4717103f341f">copy</button>
    </div>
</div>
<p>Here is a source block meant to communicate commands to be run interactively. Thus, there is no filename and I am omitting the label.  The copy button is [approximately] aligned with the first row of the source block. This is nearly where I want it, except that it's not overlapping the pre.</p>

<div class="source-block">
    <div class="org-src-container">
        <pre class="src src-sh">echo "command 1"
        echo "command 2"
        echo "command 3"
        echo "command 4"
        echo "command 5"
        echo "command 6"
        echo "command 7"
        echo "command 8"
        echo "command 9"
        </pre>
        <button class="copyBtn" name="btn_6b6c6f15f31f4a1cb9f8af9bcf6c5e7d">copy</button>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, I don't have the freedom the change anything inside <div class="org-src-container"></div>. i.e., I cannot move the `label` *before* <div class="org-src-container"> (without writing additional `lisp` code. Is there a `css` solution given this limitation? I updated my question to clarify the limitation.

Comment: You cannot "relate" `<pre>` with the `<button>` when you may / may not have other elements in the same container, unless your `<pre>` block height is fixed, then you can align the button to the bottom edge and give a fixed bottom margin.